# How can I request permission to serial port android using C

Tags: android, serial-port, java-native-interface, native

Currently my device connects to USB-serial adapter to a printer.  I'm looking for how to send data to printer via serial port "/dev/ttyUSB0" but I'm getting error "Operation not permitted" from the call chmod().  It's the call to request for permission to open the port because if i don't request for permission, I'm getting "Access denied" from calling Open().

Let's say my port is "/dev/ttyUSB0" and the permission is to send data to port.

Below is the call to chmod().  Thanks.

```
JNIEXPORT jint JNICALL Java_com_example_testserialport_ExecuteTest_RequestPermission(JNIEnv *env, jobject obj, jstring port)
{        
    LOGI("entering RequestPermission()");

    int retVal = 0;
    mode_t permission = S_IWUSR;//request to write to port

    jboolean iscopy;
    const char *path_utf = (*env)->GetStringUTFChars(env, port, &iscopy);
    retVal = chmod(path_utf, permission);
    if(retVal == -1)
    {
        LOGE("inside RequestPermission()- chmod() failed");
        LOGE("inside RequestPermission()- chmod()- errno=%s", strerror(errno));
        return -1;
    }

    LOGI(ANDROID_LOG_INFO, TAG, "exiting RequestPermission()");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You're asking the wrong question,  which is an [XY question](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem), because you're trying to solve the **open()** problem with the wrong solution..  If your username joined the `dialout` group, then your program would have access to `/dev/ttyUSB0`.

Comment: when I try to call open(), it returns back as "Access denied."  I search online that I need to request for permission so that is why I call chmod() to request for permission, but got error on "Operation not permitted."  So now after searching more on google, it seems I need to change user ID and group ID.  Since I'm new to android and serial port, I didn't know that I have to be right user and group to access the port.

Comment: Why do you choose to believe what you found in your search, rather than what I wrote?  Changing the owner or group of the device node is not the proper solution to using that device.  That would circumvent the security mechanism.  If you don't like security, then use Windows.  *"I didn't know that I have to be right user and group to access the port"* -- Incorrect; either you have to be the owner ***or*** in the group to use the device.

Comment: I didn't say that I don't like the security.   About having to be in the correct group as I previously stated, I think I misunderstood.  So anyway i was searching for command to check what group is /dev/ttyUSB0 in and found that the file is not in dailout group.  I type "adb shell ls -l /dev/ttyUSB0" and it returns back: "crw-rw---- system sdcard_rw 188, 0 2016-03-06 14:16 ttyUSB0"